# Deploying ASP.NET Core Web API and ASP.NET Core with Angular in a subfolder (1&1 Windows Business Hosting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, web-deployment

I've acquired a 1&1 Windows Business Hosting which allows to deploy ASP.NET Core applications (so yeah, I have no access to IIS solutions of building as application stuff or that kind of things I've seen in other posts). I wanted to deploy a web and an API in different subfolders within the 1&1 server I've acquired.

***What I want to achieve is the following:***

Imagine that my domain is https://myDomain. com.

If a user access directly that URL he should see a specific page of the Angular Web App. However, if the called is https://myDomain. com/api/controllerName it should do whatever I have programmed in that controller of the Web API.

I want to have the folder structure something like this:

[image: Folder configuration 1]

But it is also valid if I manage to get it like this:

[image: Folder configuration 2]

Is any of these two cases even possible to be done? If possible, how I should proceed for being able to do it? I don't have a lot of knowledge in these topics related to web deployment.

***What I have managed to do up until now:***

If I deploy just the ASP.NET Core Web API outside the subfolder it works with no issues. If I deploy just the ASP.NET Core with Angular outside the subfolder it also works. My issue is that I'm unable to get them both to work at the same time when at least one of them is in a subfolder.

Alternatives on how to achieve this are also welcome!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy ASP.NET Core Web API and ASP.NET Core with Angular in two folders as shown in the image below.

These two folders are virtual directories in IIS. If you want to specify which app to access by default, you can modify the rewrite rule in web.config under the wwwroot folder.

[image]